# Saving simple user input in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have built this simple todo app, however it resets the data every time the users page is reset, how can I save the data in the checklist list upon page refresh so the user can reference it later? Can this be done within the app or do I need a server database setup?

```
var checkList = angular.module('checkList', []);

checkList.filter('checkedItems', function () {
return function (items, showComplete) {
    var resultArr = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        if (item.done == false || showComplete == true) {
            resultArr.push(item);
        }
    });
    return resultArr;
}
});

checkList.controller('CheckListCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.check = {
user: "Jim",
items: [ {action: "item1", done: false },
{action: "item2", done: false },
{action: "item3", done: false },
{action: "item4", done: false }]
   };

   $scope.incompleteCount = function () {
       var count = 0;
       angular.forEach($scope.check.items, function (item) {
           if (!item.done) { count++ }
       });
       return count;
   }
   $scope.warningLevel = function () {
       return $scope.incompleteCount()
       < 3 ? "label-success" : "label-warning";
   }
   $scope.addNewItem = function (actionText) {
       $scope.check.items.push({ action: actionText, done: false });
   }
     });
```

Comment: Take a look at Web Storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: You can use a database if you need to persist it off-site (eg: save data to their account). Or for simply persisting the data for that browser you can utilize local storage/cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

To save data in browser's local storage: `localStorage.setItem('itemName', data)` and then, to retrieve it back `localStorage.getItem('itemName', data)`

Comment: A sI am new to angular and development in general, would I use "items" as the item name considering the user can set the actual name?